# Weird placement on page load with parallax

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, parallax

I'm working on adjusting a Wordpress theme using parallax to a logo I've developed for an event.

Basically I've just replaced the original elements with opaque layers of the new logo and have then repositioned them to layer directly on top of each other. The problem is that after I've done this, the placement or the display of the logo is different on page load than it is after a scrolling event is registered.

I have very little experience with parallax or javascript. The site is at http://www.foodprint.se The console errors I'm getting in chrome are:

> body.scrollTop is deprecated in strict mode. Please use
>   'documentElement.scrollTop' if in strict mode and 'body.scrollTop'
>   only if in quirks mode. jquery.js:4 body.scrollLeft is deprecated in
>   strict mode. Please use 'documentElement.scrollLeft' if in strict mode
>   and 'body.scrollLeft' only if in quirks mode. jquery.js:4 Object
>   {type: "refresh", state: Object} state: Object type: "refresh"
>   **proto**: Object  script.js:192 event.returnValue is deprecated. Please use the standard event.preventDefault() instead. jquery.js:3
>   Object {type: "refresh", state: Object} state: Object type: "refresh"
>   **proto**: Object

I would appreciate any tips which could send me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are facing is general one for `chrome`.....it uses `body.scrollTop` to represent the view-port's scroll position in standards mode.

Possible reason i can think of is that the makers of `chrome` want the developers to switch to more formal or universal style of coding....as for other browsers like Mozilla, I don't think your problem would be there *(have you checked in other browsers too !!? looks fine on my mozilla :) )*

You can check out  [**this Git**](https://github.com/facebook/react/pull/643)  for a fix if it helps!!!

Also, if its okay to use jquery,  [see this link](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-equivalent-of-document-body-scrolltop-document-documentelement-scrolltop) , it shows the equivalent of `body.scrollTop`

**EDIT**

In your file **layout.css**

you have set `margin: 700px 0 0 0;` for `#header`.....this is causing the page to render the drop only after scroll...change the `700px` to `0px`

Now, to place the content after drop, ammend `#header .content` section in same file to below :

```
#header .content {
    margin: 700px 0 20px 0; /* previously it was 0 0 20px 0 */
    line-height: 18px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Mayank, but I'm getting the same behavior in Safari or Firefox. I heard it was fixed in the latest version of Chrome, but I'm still having the problem. The logo initially appears at the bottom of the window, and then on scroll jumps up to the top. Thanks though, I'll have a look at that Jquery, though honestly I'm not so sure where to implement it.

Comment: by logo you mean the `tri-color` image mix-up in the middle of the page above `India unlimited`???

Comment: yea, exactly, the drop looking thing

Comment: wierd, well, that's great, but it's definitely jumping for me. https://www.dropbox.com/s/7d58hvls8b06vu3/Screenshot%202013-12-20%2009.53.04.png

Comment: ok...my bad...on page load the drop is not appearing, it appearing only after scroll start...lemme check why so!!!

Comment: @bubbaJackson : pheww....done mate...added the edit, now....edit your code, make it work then accept this answer for me!!